# A/B framework for Rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, abtest

Is there anything like ABingo or Vanity that works in Rails 3?  I know there's Google Website Optimizer, and Visual Website optimizer, but I need more power w/ regard to determining what is displayed, and what is in turn tracked than they can provide.  If not, I'll even take thoughts on frameworks that are relatively simple enough that I might be able to convert them to Rails 3 compliance easily.

Comment: Hi Jeff, did you ever find an alternative for rails 3? stuck in the same situation at the moment.

Comment: No I'm afraid I didn't, and wound up sidetracked w/ other things.  You may want to check out optimizely.  They had a deal on appsumo.com the other day.  Not sure if it's still live.  They seemed to be getting decent press, so I signed up, but haven't had a chance to get back to that.

Comment: Any progress on this question?

Comment: I just heard about a project called split, that I'm going to try out: https://github.com/andrew/split

Answer (score 1):

Andy Atkinson has written Rails 3 Getting Started guides for [A/Bingo](http://webandy.com/articles/getting-started-with-a-bingo-and-rails-3) and [Vanity](http://webandy.com/articles/a-b-testing-with-vanity).